# Set Parameter if blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to set the `id` parameter to a value if it is wasn't submitted with the form.

Is it ok to do something like this in Rails or does this violate any standards or cause possible issues?

```
if params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id].blank?
  params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id] = 1234 #default id
end
```

My implementation works with this logic, but I am not sure if this is the proper way to handle the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance `[:record_type]` is nil which will lead to an undefined method error when you attempt to call `[:id]` on `nil`. Additionally, I'd find it a bit weird to directly mutate params, even though you technically *can* do that. I'd consider using Strong Parameter processing methods like so (added a full action, which isn't in your sample, to give more context on how this would be used):

```
def create
  @record_type = RecordType.new(record_type_params)

  if record_type.save
    redirect_to @record_type
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def record_type_params
  params.require(:record_type).permit(:id).reverse_merge(id: 1234)
end
```

The [`reverse_merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-reverse_merge) call is a way to merge the user-supplied parameters into your defaults. This accomplishes what you're after in what I would consider a more conventional way and doesn't mutate `params`.

Comment: Ok, so I have a case where I have nested address attributes on a shopping cart. I'm wanting to set the id in case the user goes to another tab and submits the original form (which creates addresses rather than updates the addresses saved in the database). With this case, instead of updating the current addresses, more addresses are created. I figured that setting the id parameter of the nested attribute would solve the issue. How would this need to look with the reverse_merge? I've updated the question with the exact param value I am trying to change.

Comment: I wouldn't embed this logic directly into the model, though (most likely). Here it's specific to a submitted form/API call, which may not be universally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cart_params
  params.require(:cart).permit(:cart_addresses_attributes => [:id]).tap do |p|
    p[:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:id] ||= 1234
  end
end
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
if params[:record_type][:id].nil? # or replace ".nil?" with "== nil"
params[:record_type][:id] = 1234
end
```

personally, this is the way I prefer to do it. Some ways are more efficient than others, but if that works for you I'd roll with it.

Comment: Un-set values (including hidden) will be blank, not nil.

Comment: @DaveNewton So is my original implementation the way to go? Thoughts?